# Animated Space series from 80s or 90s identification

Tags: story-identification, space, cartoon

Could anyone help me with my memories of this series? I'm looking for a series that I remember these things from:

- The main villain, or one of the main villains, reminds pretty much of Darth Vader, but his brain is visible, it is inside a dome on his head.
- The same villain battles the hero, or one of the heroes, and falls down a volcano. I don't remember if he survived, but shortly after that, a female version of this villain is revealed (like his sister or something?).
- The whole series is animated and takes place in space and on different planets.
- The main character/hero is either looking for his father, or his father is lost somewhere in space.
- The team is made up of the usual Star Wars-clones (i.e. one Luke, one Solo, one robot).

Now, I might of course mix separate cartoons into one, but the strongest memory is the villain falling into the volcano. I'm pretty sure it is not G-Force, although Zoltan fits quite well. It is probably not Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors too, because the Monster Minds don't quite fit the profile (at least of what I can remember).

I am also not sure if this series had a toy line or something. One thing is for sure: it did not come after the year 2000.

:)

Comment: If it was from the 1980s, it's unlikely that the cartoon spawned a toy line. It's far more likely that the cartoon was advertising ***for*** the toy line :-)

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Yes, if it did so then that would be likely.

Comment: Apart from the villain falling into a volcano and being replaced by a female version, everything else described does sound very like Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors.